# Unable to do robot framework reports collection in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, robotframework, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to run *4 test scripts* in parallel. I want to store the `output.xml` file for each test script in the following manner-

```
 Test_1 -> output1.xml
 Test_2 -> output2.xml
 .
 .
 Test_4 -> output3.xml
```

and combine them together and generate one single `report.html` file
I'm getting some errors related to the output.xml file location.

There is my script in `Jenkins` to run the robot-

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers {
        cron('H */4 * * 1-5')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Testing') {
            parallel{
                stage('Testing- Operator') {
                        steps { 
                               sh '''robot //var//jenkins_home//workspace//Testing_Operator//Operator.robot 
                               robot  archiveDirName:\'robot-plugin\',logFileName: \'**/log*.html\',outputFileName:\'**/output*.xml\',outputPath:\'/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Testing_Pipeline\',overwriteXAxisLabel: \'\',reportFileName:\'**/report*.html\''''  
                        }
                }
                
                stage('Testing -Manager') {
                        steps {
                               sh '''robot //var//jenkins_home//workspace//Testing_Manger//Manager.robot 
                               robot  archiveDirName:\'robot-plugin\',logFileName: \'**/log*.html\',outputFileName:\'**/output*.xml\',outputPath:\'/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Testing_Pipeline\',overwriteXAxisLabel: \'\',reportFileName:\'**/report*.html\''''  
                        }
                }
                
                stage('Testing -Admin') {
                        steps {
                               sh '''robot //var//jenkins_home//workspace//Testing_Admin//Admin.robot 
                               robot  archiveDirName:\'robot-plugin\',logFileName: \'**/log*.html\',outputFileName:\'**/output*.xml\',outputPath:\'/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Testing_Pipeline\',overwriteXAxisLabel: \'\',reportFileName:\'**/report*.html\''''  
                        }
                }
                
                stage('Testing -Owner') {
                        steps {
                                sh '''robot //var//jenkins_home//workspace//Testing_Owner//Owner.robot 
                                robot  archiveDirName:\'robot-plugin\',logFileName: \'**/log*.html\',outputFileName:\'**/output*.xml\',outputPath:\'/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Testing_Pipeline\',overwriteXAxisLabel: \'\',reportFileName:\'**/report*.html\''''  
                        }       
                }
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Here is the error-

> **Output:**  /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Testing_Pipeline/output.xml
> **[ ERROR ]** Reading XML source '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Testing_Pipeline/output.xml'
> failed: ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line xx, column xx

What could be the possible cause of the error? Is the syntax correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the `output.xml` is broken due to running `robot` in parallel.

What you can do is for all the `robot` commands to use the flag for a different output path (or filename), and in a final stage call `rebot` to produce the final report and logs.